# What does the vertical bar means in this B-Spline evaluation formula

Tags: spline

I have a homework with the problem set like the following:

When a B-spline is evaluated at one of its knots it can be simplified according to the formula

$B(t_i | t_j,...,t_{j+1+p}) = B(t_i | t_j,...,t_{i-1},t_{i+1},t_{j+1+p})$

What does the vertical bar means here?
 I can see that the right hand side skips $t_i$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess ...

The vertical bar just serves to separate the function argument from other numbers that are used in the function's definition.

So, $B(t | t_r, \ldots , t_s)$ denotes the value at $t$ of the b-spline that is constructed from the knots $t_r, \ldots , t_s$.